# Changer text from array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning jQuery and JS. I have text in:

`<p><em>"My text 1"</em></p>`

How can I implement simple text slider (maybe array with texts and it will be change after 5s)? What function can I use?
I need in array:

```
"My text 1"
"My text text"
"My text my text"
"My text other"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myTexts = new Array("My text 1", 
                        "My text text", 
                        "My text my text", 
                        "My text other");
var currentText = 0;

var timeout = setInterval(nextText, 5000);

function nextText() {
    if (currentText >= myTexts.length) {
        currentText = 0;
    } else {
        currentText++;
    }

    $('em').html(myTexts[currentText]);
}
```

Basically what the code above does is:

1. set your text within an array
2. set an interval to call nextText() every 5 seconds
3. in the function check which text to show (based on the length of your array)
4. change the text within your 'em' element with jquery's html()-method.

-edit: typos...

Answer (score 0):

Settimeout function. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#yourDivId').html('<p><em>Another text</em></p>');
      }, 2000);

})
```

This will change text in your div after 2 sec.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var terms = ["My text 1", "My text text", "My text my text", "My text other"];

function rotateTerm() {
    var ct = $("#rotate").data("term") || 0;
    $("#rotate").data("term", ct == terms.length -1 ? 0 : ct + 1)
                .text(terms[ct])
                .fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut(200, rotateTerm);
};
rotateTerm();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WdTkN/1/)**

Comment: @user3284589 Right. `$(function(){` is shorter.

Comment: @user3284589 Yes, you need to do so.